# Change width constraint of a Button in StackView Programmatically

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview, ios-autolayout

I have a stackView which contains some UItextfields and one button.
I have constrained it in ViewController viewDidLoad like this:

```
let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 40
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.alignment = .fill
     
     stackView.addArrangedSubview(justAskYouSomeInfosLabel)
     stackView.addArrangedSubview(emailTextField)
     stackView.addArrangedSubview(passwordTextField)
     stackView.addArrangedSubview(againPasswordTextField)
     stackView.addArrangedSubview(registrationButton)
     
     
             //autolayout the stackview
     view.addSubview(stackView)
     stackView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 80, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
     stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
     stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
```

Now I want to reduce the width of the button on the bottom of the stackView.

I tried this:

```
registrationButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
```

as suggested on other stackOverflow questions but it doesn't work and I receive this error on the console:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
```

How can I reduce the width of the button programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

from the line `stackView.alignment = .fill` you agree that the width of subviews of UIStackView has the same width as its parent

Change it as `stackView.alignment = .center` or `stackView.alignment = .leading` so that you can set width of button different from its parent.

Comment: thanks for the answer I tried it and it actually displays only the button on the center and the other textfields disappear

Comment: I see, other subviews are textField so they have no width. The labels should be fine in this case. So, you need to set the width constraint of textFields as `textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true`

Comment: You need to define other anchors as well for other UI elements of the StackView. Changing single-width constraint with constant value causing changes in other elements value.

Comment: Thanks, now I used your suggestion and it works. I guessed that there'd be a simpler way to customise just one width, but anyway it works so thank u! :)

Comment: You can even set button constraint programmatically so that it will not set to full width. `button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0).isActive = true`